# GCP Bucket - create link for upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've looked all over but can't seem to see how this might be done.

I have a GCP bucket, which is publicly accessible. I need a link to give to an associate which they can use to upload some files into that bucket. There is no need for authentication, the files are just public domain anyway. I need the process to be super simple for the associate.

Once the files are uploaded I can grab them and destroy the bucket/project anyway.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).  From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> In some scenarios, you might not want to require your users to have a Google account in order to access Cloud Storage, but you still want to control access using your application-specific logic. The typical way to address this use case is to **provide a signed URL to a user, which gives the user read, write, or delete access to that resource for a limited time**. You specify an expiration time when you create the signed URL. Anyone who knows the URL can access the resource until the expiration time for the URL is reached or the key used to sign the URL is rotated.